Требуются ли запятые?
«Если в этом мире есть другой, маленький У Хиджэ…» — нужна ли тут запятая после «другой»?
«То возможно ли, что где-то существует и второй меч Ю Джиын?» — нужна ли тут запятая после «то»?

Если в этом мире есть другой(?) маленький У Хиджэ , то возможно ли, что где-то существует и второй меч Ю Джиын?
Мне кажется, что это одно предложение.
• О первой запятой
Если предполагается, что оба У Хидже являются маленькими, то запятая не нужна:
есть другой маленький У Хиджэ (= такой же, еще один, второй; неоднородные определения).
Если же предполагается, что имеются и большой, и маленький, то запятая ставится:
есть другой, маленький У Хиджэ (= иной, не такой, отличающийся; уточняющие согласованные определения).

Обычно определения с уточняющим значением рассматриваются как однородные, то есть запятая ставится не с двух сторон, а с одной – между определениями.
Быстрыми шагами прошёл я длинную «площадь» кустов, взобрался на холм и... увидел совершенно другие, незнакомые мне места (Тургенев).

• О второй запятой
Это сложноподчиненное предложение, в котором возможно ли является сказуемым, а не вводным словом (проверьте: убрать из предложения нельзя!), имеет значение может ли быть и запятой не отделяется.
Наличие частицы "ли", собственно, и делает это предложение вопросительным.
• О мече
Если Ю Джиын — женщина, то написано все правильно (меч Ю Джиын; не склоняется).
Если Ю Джиын — мужчина, то надо склонять (меч Ю Джиына).
Если Ю Джиын — это название меча, то необходимы кавычки (меч «Ю Джиын»).
Значения слова другой
Уточняющие, пояснительные и присоединительные члены предложения
